# How do i program this function switch in simulink?

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I am trying to make a switching function for a simulink function block. Currently and faulty:

```
function y  = Switch(SOC,Input,Launch,Charge,A)
%#codegen
y = A;
if ((Launch == 1), (SOC ~= Input))
    y = Charge;
else
    y = A;
end
```

I want the output y to be the same as A unless the Launch is 1 and SOC is different from Input, in that case I want y = Charge. Another block takes care of comparing SOC and Input driving the Charge current.

How do i modify this code to get the correct switching. As an addon the y = Charge should hold until SOC = Input and then reset back to y = A;

Comment: Replace that comma in `if` statement with `&&`.

Comment: The [Switch block](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/switch.html) with appropriate inputs can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want:

```
function y  = Switch(SOC,Input,Launch,Charge,A)
%#codegen
y = A;
if (Launch == 1) && (SOC ~= Input)
    y = Charge;
else
    y = A;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup Syntax error :-D  && did the trick